# HTC flashlite player crash

Tags: android, webview

I'm having a problem with htc's flash lite player on a htc desire hd phone. Even when it had adobe flash player installed, the webview still used the htc flash lite player which crashed even on a simple youtube video.

I'm using this to check flash:

```
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
        ApplicationInfo ai = pm.getApplicationInfo("com.adobe.flashplayer", 0);
        Log.d("Flash version Installed: " + pm.getPackageInfo("com.adobe.flashplayer", 0).versionName);
        if (ai != null){
            Log.d("flash present...OK");
        }
        ApplicationInfo ai2 = pm.getApplicationInfo("com.htc.flashliteplugin", 0);
        if (ai2 != null){
            Log.d("flash lite present..disabling flash");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
```

And also:

```
if(aboveCode){    
   webview.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
}
```

So right now, I had to disable flash entirely if flash lite was present. Any ideas or solutions to this problem?
I'm avare that there are new [methods](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setPluginState%28android.webkit.WebSettings.PluginState%29) in newer api levels that might help, but I would not like to increase api level on something as stupid as this.

Comment: Did you find a solution for only disabling the htc.desire plugin?